# Update one MySQL table with values from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update one MySQL table based on information from another.

My `original` table looks like:

```
id | value
------------
1  | hello
2  | fortune
3  | my
4  | old
5  | friend
```

And the `tobeupdated` table looks like:

```
uniqueid | id | value
---------------------
1        |    | something
2        |    | anything
3        |    | old
4        |    | friend
5        |    | fortune
```

I want to update `id` in `tobeupdated` with the `id` from `original` based on `value` (strings stored in `VARCHAR(32)` field).

The updated table will hopefully look like:

```
uniqueid | id | value
---------------------
1        |    | something
2        |    | anything
3        | 4  | old
4        | 5  | friend
5        | 2  | fortune
```

I have a query that works, but it's very slow:

```
UPDATE tobeupdated, original
SET tobeupdated.id = original.id
WHERE tobeupdated.value = original.value
```

This maxes out my CPU and eventually leads to a timeout with only a fraction of the updates performed (there are several thousand values to match). I know matching by `value` will be slow, but this is the only data I have to match them together.

Is there a better way to update values like this? I could create a third table for the merged results, if that would be faster?

I tried [MySQL - How can I update a table with values from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384044/mysql-how-can-i-update-a-table-with-values-from-another-table), but it didn't really help. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your 'value' column have an index?

Comment: Hi noodl; no, `value` doesn't have an index at the moment.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

```
UPDATE tobeupdated
INNER JOIN original ON (tobeupdated.value = original.value)
SET tobeupdated.id = original.id
```

That should do it, and really its doing exactly what yours is. However, I prefer 'JOIN' syntax for joins rather than multiple 'WHERE' conditions, I think its easier to read

As for running slow, how large are the tables? You should have indexes on `tobeupdated.value` and `original.value`

EDIT: 
we can also simplify the query

```
UPDATE tobeupdated
INNER JOIN original USING (value)
SET tobeupdated.id = original.id
```

`USING` is shorthand when both tables of a join have an identical named `key` such as `id`. ie an equi-join - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Equi-join

Comment: Thanks wired00! This works perfectly. The tables are quite large (`original` is 100,000+ entries and `tobeupdated` 10,000+), so I took your and noodl's advice about the indexes and the whole query now finishes in under a second. I can't believe the difference!? Thanks so much for your help; I've learnt a lot!

Comment: Thats great to hear :) I learn a lot on here too. I really like this site as you can be exposed to many different issues and ideas

Comment: thank you.. I tried so many things from stackoverflow.. this one finally worked

Comment: Just wanted to mention that a simple UPDATE with WHERE was much faster than the JOIN syntax. About 10.000 rows.

Comment: They key ingredient is of course assigning as index. took me to update 300K records in 4 seconds as opposed to timeouts without them.

Comment: Is `inner join` doing anything here that a regular join wouldn't? (I'm about to run a similar query, but the two tables have identical columns.)

Comment: Wonderful, worked like charm. Saved a lot of time bro!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is a use of those tables, but you might consider putting trigger on original table on insert and update. When insert or update is done, update the second table based on only one item from the original table. It will be quicker.

Comment: Thanks firegnom; I've never used triggers before, but I'll be sure to read up on them.