# Indexing sql columns to speed up join query

Tags: mysql, sql

On the first answer on this post: [Update one MySQL table with values from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727827/update-one-mysql-table-with-values-from-another) 
it states that in order to speed up the query an index must be created. How do I do this?

I know it's fairly simple I just can't figure out how..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to create index (official doc)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` ADD INDEX `your_index_name` 
    (`column_that_should_be_indexed`)
```

The **[general syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)** for creating an index is as follows -

```
CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_type]

index_col_name:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]

index_type:
    USING {BTREE | HASH}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical syntax is:

```
 create index <index name> on <tablename>(<one or more columns>);
```

For instance:

```
create index t_col1_col2 on t(col1, col2);
```

Note that you also create indexes when you declare a column to be a primary key or unique (or add a unique constraint).

Also, indexes are sometimes most effective when they are *composite* -- that is, they contain more than one column.