# Sub query returns more than one row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a point of sale software in php

So I've saved the items in the cart in a temporary table called tempsales, then update all the quantity of items with the new quantities. Just one query,  using the code below which gives me subquery, returns:

> More than one row error

```
UPDATE items SET quantity = quantity -
    (SELECT quantity FROM tempsales ORDER BY id ASC) 
WHERE id  IN 
    (SELECT id FROM ORDER BY I'd ASC)
```

Comment: The problem is that your subquery `(SELECT quantity FROM tempsales ORDER BY id ASC) ` returns more than a result, so you can't do the subtraction

Comment: I think this question addresses your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727827/update-one-mysql-table-with-values-from-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to update a whole mess of rows in your `items` table based on the rows in your `tempsales` table. I think you want to match the `id` values. That requires using `JOIN` syntax in your `UPDATE` query, like this.

```
   UPDATE items
     JOIN tempsales ON items.id = tempsales.id
      SET items.quantity = items.quantity - tempsales.quantity
```