# SQL - copy data from one table column to another table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, sql-update

As you can see from the image I have a table called `wpw8_postmeta` where it has four columns and I have searched for the term release and got the following results.

I want to copy the results (release_date [meta_value]) to another table called `wpw8_test` using the `post_id` as foreign key/primary key.

[image]

The second table looks like this

[image]

After the update will be done it should look like this

[image]

Comment: what column types are meta_value and relase_date?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Show what you can do, don't ask us to write your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update one MySQL table with values from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727827/update-one-mysql-table-with-values-from-another)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the `update ... join` syntax:

```
update wpw8_test t
inner join wpw8_postmeta p on p.post_id = t.post_id
set t.release_date = p.meta_value
where p.meta_key like '%release%'
```